# Scaling a Panel, formula issue

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to scale a panel to fit it's parent panel, which I have accomplished By doing this:

```
 ValSize = New Size(basePanel.Width - 20, basePanel.Height - 20)
```

This works well, but now I want to add another panel (dragItem) to this one I just scaled down (basePanel), but I need to keep the scaling the same between the 2 panels so they are not the same size but scaled the same mount. I was trying to use this formula to find how much I scaled the first item and get a percentage and use that for the new panel.

```
Dim scaleWidth As Double = Math.Abs(basePanel.Width - dragItem.Width) / dragItem.Width
```

Whats the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the ratio you are only supposed to divide.

- **Ratio of a smaller panel compared to the original:**

  ```
  Dim scaleWidth As Double = otherPanel.Width / basePanel.Width
  ```

  Returns values <= 1

  ‌‌
- **Ratio of the original panel compared to a smaller:**

  ```
  Dim scaleWidth As Double = basePanel.Width / otherPanel.Width
  ```

  Returns values >= 1

So if you have a panel that is 200px wide and a smaller one that is 150px wide, the ratio will be **0.75**. To create a new panel from this based on the smaller panel you would do:

```
Dim newWidth As Integer = scaleWidth * otherPanel.Width
```

Since `scaleWidth` is 0.75 and `otherPanel.Width` is 150, you will get the following result: `0.75 * 150 = 113` *(112,5 to be exact, but it's rounded since it's an integer)*.

Now your third panel will be 25% smaller than the second panel. The second panel in turn is 25% smaller than the original panel.

Comment: I really apperciate your help. I wasn't looking at it correctly. Dumb of me!

Comment: @goomba454 : No problem. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Although it's possible, you don't need to do this calculations by yourself. Instead, set each panel's dock property to `Fill` and set the padding of the container as you like. In this case it's seems to want equal padding for every container.